# presenting Unix Timestamps with Swift

Tags: swift, unix-timestamp

Using a current timestamp and a given timestamp, what is the best way to present them on a page? If the given timestamp represents "yesterday" the presentation should say yesterday. if the given timestamp was minutes or hours ago, it should only include how many. etc. is it best to subtract one from the other and evaluate what the difference means or is there a built-in library or framework that can be used? so far I am working with the following playground:

```
    let ts = 1499299978.149724
    let current_ts: Double

    let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: ts)

    let dayTimePeriodFormatter = DateFormatter()

    let totalFormat  = "MMM dd YYYY hh:mm a" //just for reference
    dayTimePeriodFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a" //add to this as desired

    let dateString = dayTimePeriodFormatter.string(from: date as Date)
```

Comment: Your question seems to be about formatting the difference between two `Date` instances, correct? Please edit your title accordingly. Your question has nothing to do with Unix timestamps. And why use `NSDate` instead of `Date`?

Comment: And please update your question with specific examples of the type of output your want. Your description is very vague.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

this should get you started:

```
    let midnight = startOfToday.timeIntervalSince1970
    let secondsInADay = 86400.0

    if ts > midnight {
        print ("today")
        code
    } else if ts > midnight - secondsInADay {
        print ("yesterday")
        code
    } else if ts > midnight - secondsInADay - secondsInADay {
        print ("2 days ago")
        code
    } else if ts > midnight - secondsInADay * 3 {
        print ("3 days ago")
        code
    }
```

inside the "today" block you can use a similar process to check for seconds ago, minutes ago, else then subtract the ts from the current ts then divide by 60 accordingly to get the number you need

Comment: Don't use 86400 seconds as the duration of a day. A day can have 23 or 25 hours if the clocks are adjusted for daylight savings time.

Comment: What is `startOfToday`? FYI - do not use this approach. Use the appropriate `Calendar` methods.

Comment: so don't use this but use something else? something appropriate. not going to actually answer just criticize. I used it and it works.